# MYSQL - on update one table automatically delete rows in second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in relation 1:n

```
create table A (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data VARCHAR(32),
    data2 INTEGER,
    INDEX (id)
);
CREATE TABLE B (
    A_id BINGINT,
    some_data DOUBLE,
    INDEX (A_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (A_id) REFERENCES A(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If i update a row in table A then i need to delete all records from table B with same id from table A. What is the best way to solve it?
i dont know if i should use a trigger or an event.

Comment: Do these actions need to happen atomically?

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger on table A:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE UPDATE ON A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM B WHERE a_id = NEW.id;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```